# Read environment variable value with cheerio

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I am parsing a webpage and trying to get the text values from it.

I am using [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/) to be able to do this with `node.js`.

Currently whenever I parse a tag it returns `{{status}}` this is because the value is an environment variable, but I want to be able to read the actual value (in this case it is "2").

This is what I have currently got:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const url = 'my url';
const $ = require('cheerio');

rp(url)
  .then(function(html){
    //success!
    console.log($('.class-name div', html).text());
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    //handle error
  });
```

I have also tried using `.html()`, `.contents()` but still not success.

Do I have to change the second parameter in `$('.class-name DIV', <PARAMETER>)` to achieve what I am after?

Comment: is `{{status}}` is a javascript code that you want to display its value?

Comment: @EdiImanto Yes, it is

Comment: Then you can eval the response text

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide any URL or HTML you're trying to parse.
So, with cheerio, you can use selector like this format.

```
$( selector, [context], [root] )
```

Means search the selector inside context, within root element (usually HTML doc string), `selector` and `context` can be a string expression, DOM Element, array of DOM elements, or cheerio object.

Meanwhile:
`$(selector).text()` => Return innerText of the selector
`$(selector).html()` => Return innerHTML of the selector
`$(selector).attr('class')` => Return value of class attribute

---

But cheerio parser is difficult to debug.
I've used cheerio for a while and sometimes this can be a headache.
So i've found `jsonframe-cheerio`, a package that parse that HTML tags for you.

In this working example below, as you can see it parse cheerio perfectly.
It will translate a format called frame to extract `innerText`, attributes value, even filter or match some regular expression.

---

HTML source (simplified for readibility)
https://www.example.com

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CHeerIO

```
const request = require ('request-promise')
const cheerio = require ('cheerio')
const jsonfrm = require ('jsonframe-cheerio')
const url = 'https://www.example.com'
let $ = null

;(async () => {
    try {

        const response = await request(url)
        $ = cheerio.load (response)
        jsonfrm($)

        let frame = {
            articles : { // This format will loop every matching selectors occurs
                _s : "body > div", // The root of every repeating item
                _d : [{
                    "titling" : "h1", // The innerText of article h1
                    "excerpt" : "p",  // The innerText of article content p
                    "linkhref": "a[href] @ href" // The value of href attribute within a link
                }]
            }
        }

        const displayResult = $('body').scrape(frame, { string: true } )

        console.log ( displayResult )

    } catch ( error ) {
        console.log ('ERROR: ', error)
    }
})()
```